# Draw an n-gon with Polytopes package?

Tags: graphics

Given $n$, I'm interested in generating the vertices of a regular $n$-gon. I noticed
that this was possible for certain values of $n$ using the `Polytopes` package; e.g., via

```
<< Polytopes` 

Vertices[Heptagon]; 

Graphics[{PointSize[0.025], Point /@ %}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

Is it possible to plot, say, the vertices of a regular 17-gon with `Polytopes`, or do I need to resort to something like calling `CompleteGraph` and extracting vertices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
vertices[n_Integer?Positive] :=
 ({Cos[2 Pi #/n], Sin[2 Pi #/n]} & /@
   Range[n])

Manipulate[
 Module[
  {vert = vertices[n]},
  Graphics[{
    Line[{{0, 0}, #}] & /@ vert,
    LightBlue,
    Opacity[.5],
    EdgeForm[Black],
    Polygon[vert]}]],
 {{n, 17}, Range[3, 20]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't *need to* but you can

> ***resort to something like calling CompleteGraph and extracting vertices***

```
nGon = Module[{coords = GraphEmbedding @ CompleteGraph @ #}, 
    Graphics[{Opacity[.5, LightBlue], EdgeForm[Gray], Polygon @ coords, 
      Gray, Line /@ Thread[{coords, Mean[coords]}, List, 1], Red, 
      PointSize[Medium], Point @ coords}]] &;

nGon @ 17
```

[image]

With the `` Polytopes` `` package, you are limited to n-gons where `n` is one of

```
NumberOfVertices /@ ToExpression /@ Names["Polytopes`*gon"]
```

> {10, 2, 12, 7, 6, 9, 8, 5, 11}

**Note:** You can use [`CirclePoints`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CirclePoints.html)  instead of `GraphEmbedding` + `CompleteGraph` combination if you have version 10.1+.